# How to use library(circlize) in R when matrix is not symmetric

Tags: r, visualization, geometry, circlize

I am trying to draw a flow map using the `circlize` library. My code is below and the dataset (i75_from_flow.RData) is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hTmthiX5dpbFJFc2hfN1Zqd1k/view

```
library(reshape)
t1 <- cast(i75_from_flow, ORIGFIPS ~ TERMFIPS)
i75_from_flow2<- data.matrix(subset(t1, select=-c(1)))
rownames(i75_from_flow2) <- t1$ORIGFIPS
colnames(i75_from_flow2) <- colnames(i75_from_flow2)

library(circlize)
circos.par(gap.degree = 8)
chordDiagram(i75_from_flow2, grid.col= length(union(rownames(i75_from_flow2),colnames(i75_from_flow2))), directional = TRUE, annotationTrack = "grid",
         preAllocateTracks = list(list(track.height = 0.05),
                                  list(track.height = 0.05)))

circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
sector.index = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
circos.text(mean(xlim), mean(ylim), sector.index, facing = "inside", niceFacing = TRUE)
}, bg.border = NA)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error following the **chordDiagram** and **circos.trackPlotRegion** lines in the code.

```
Error in .CELL.DATA[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

My goal is to get an image that shows the matrix cells as flows between the ORIGFIPS and TERMFIPS.

My question is how to fix error in cell data issue. Should the matrix be symmetric for circlize to work properly? It is not always the case in this effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `i75_from_flow2` contains `NA` values. Add following line:

```
i75_from_flow2[is.na(i75_from_flow2)] = 0
```

Comment: I feel ridiculous now for forgetting this simple step :-).  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Now in the new version of the package,  `chordDiagram()` will automatically convert `NA` to 0 if the input is a matrix.

Comment: That is fantastic. Thanks for update. I wrote up a small brief on how to develop these visualizations and would welcome your comments on how to improve it better. http://rpubs.com/matungawalla/circular_matrix